# List style image not working

Tags: html, wordpress, css, menu

I was working on [this site](http://webzerjob.in/Nepal). I have set a sidebar menu widget on the left sidebar.

I gave the sidebar CSS as follows

```
#menu-side1 > li {
    list-style-image:url('./images/aarow.png') !important;
}
.sub-menu li {
    list-style-image:url('./images/aarow1.png') !important;
}
```

My desired outcome is something like this:

[image]

But with the given CSS its not displaying. I don't know where I went wrong. Please help, thanks!

Comment: is image in right path?? using handlebars??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the position of the list-item icons to bring them inside the `<li>`:

```
#menu-side1 > li {
    list-style-image: url('./images/aarow.png') !important;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Comment: Glad to have helped (:

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
#menu-side1 > li::before {
    content: url('./images/aarow.png') !important;
}
```

This will allow you to keep one line of code and do much more with it (e.g. you can put some text in it)